i am getting [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied. from my udp client side code problem is only happens on windows
I have two Python applications, client side and another server side.
client side:
import socket
import threading

UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
UDP_PORT = 56780

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

nickname = input("Enter Nickname: ")
def write():
    while True:
        print("hello")
        message = f"{nickname} -> {input()}"
        client_socket.sendto(message.encode(), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message, _ = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            print(message.decode())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break


write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

server side:
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 56780

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))

clients = set()

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        server_socket.sendto(message, client)

def receive():
    print("UDP Chat Server is running...")
    while True:
        try:
            message, client_address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            if client_address not in clients:
                clients.add(client_address)
                print(f"Connected With {str(client_address)}")
            broadcast(message)
        except:
            clients.remove(client_address)
receive()

The error I am having arises from the client side application, specifically from:
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message, _ = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            print(message.decode())
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            break


The error is:

[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied

This error only happens on my Windows system. On my Mac, the code seems to work exactly as it should.
I tried different ports to see if any of them worked, but it did not.
One thing I did detriment was that I get the error when I try to bind this part of the code to my server, but I can't figure out why and how to fix it.
message, _ = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)

